# css - align label & textbox at right side of page

Tags: html, css

I have created 4 column grid in my html form. i want to have last label and textbox field to be align right side of the page.

I have tried using `float:right` property but it doesn't seem to work

In fiddle example it is not in single line.

```css
    .row {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .elements {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-bottom: ridge;
        border-bottom-color: #1f6a9a;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .field {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #b6d6ed;
    }

    label {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    input {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0px solid;
        height: 25px;
        width: 60px;
        color: #b6d6ed;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* I Tried Below Line to Right Align */
    
    .row > .elements:nth-child(2) {
        float:right;   
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <span class="elements">
            <label class="field" for="Title">Title</label>
            <input id="Title" name="Title" type="text">
        </span>
        <span class="elements">
            <label class="field" for="DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
            <input id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </span>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn5s2/)

Comment: at least it's aligned to the right, but *doesn't seem to work* is unclear on the exact effect you want.

Comment: It is floated right. Whats not working?

Comment: It is not in single line...look fiddle

Comment: @SagarDumbre This http://jsfiddle.net/Wn5s2/1/ what you want?

Comment: @SagarDumbre you should have mentioned it in your question, we cannot guess exactly what you want. We should always avoid just saying *doesn't seem to work* without any explanation/description about what's wrong and what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float the first `span` to the left:

```
.row > .elements:first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3DtqB/2/

Comment: He should also clearfix the `.row`. The float wouldn't be needed also if the `.elements` were `display: inline-block`

Comment: Yes, of course, I also think he should clearfix the `.row`, but there's no much HTML here and I don't want to guess the context. I've tried to give a specific answer to a specific question based in his fiddle.

Comment: :) just thought I'd mention, nice answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `elements` class into a `<div class=".."></div>` and add an CSS command

```
.elements {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -[x]px
}
```

Also you should use two id's instead of a class elements like `left_box` and `right_box` and add the commands to the right box.

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix, just add `white-space:nowrap;` to the `.elements` class.